# How to make Pixel variables random?

Tags: random, draw, processing, pixel, void

so Here's a piece of void draw code that I can't figure out. Please explain to me what I'm doing wrong.

```
void draw() {
loadPixels();
int x,y,offs,u,v;
offs=0;
for (y=0;y<988;y++) {
for (x=0;x<554;x++) {
u=(utab[x][y]+voffs)&255;
v=(vtab[x][y]+uoffs)&255;
pixels[offs++]=tex.pixels[(u<<8)+v];
}
}
updatePixels();
uoffs++;
voffs++;
}
```

I don't get how to make the '&255' value for 'u' and 'v' random. Could somebody please explain? Cause u=(utab[x][y]+voffs)&random(0,255) or something won't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
u=(utab[random(554)][random(988)]+voffs)&255;
```

which should probably safe, although we could help you a lot more if you posted some more code...

Comment: Never mind I fixed it using a new int! :D

    int ra = (int) random(0,250);

and then I used the int for:

    u=(utab[x][y]+voffs)&ra;

But thanks anyway!!